# Syncing WM6 <-> Evolution.... opensync-module-python missing?

Tags: 10.10, evolution, sync, smartphone

I'm trying to install `opensync-plugin-synce` to sync my wm6 phone with Evolution, but when I try (from synaptic, also with ap-get), is:

```
Depende: opensync-module-python  but it is not installable
```

In fact, I haven't found opensync-module-python in repositories.

Any hint? Is there any way to sync WM6 and Evolution (preferably without intermediate online syncs as Gmail, for instance)?

Update: `opensync-module-python` exists in the repositories for previous versions of Ubuntu (mine is 10.10).... could I install it from there or would I ruin something?

Update: should I mark this as impossible? Seems to be no way to sync WM6 phone with Evolution right now....

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm using Maverick, in case that changes anything

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following PPA to overcome that problem, the missing package is in here..

https://launchpad.net/~opensync/+archive/opensync-0.22?field.series_filter=maverick

Comment: I'll check that tomorrow and check if it works, thanks.