# How do I install synce?

Tags: sync

I was trying to install synce on ubuntu 11.10. It is used to sync windows mobile phones 5/6 using activeSync. So far I have managed to setup a a connection between the computer and my windows phone.(i.e. I see files and folders when I type synce-pls). However when I come to the actual syncing to Evolution [This](http://www.synce.org/moin/SynceInstallation/Ubuntu/ModernDevice) tells me to install "multisync-tools opensync-plugin-synce synce-sync-engine", however I cannot find the first two in the repositories.

Answer (score 3):

```
ilias@E34G-SHF3:~$ sudo apt-cache search multisync     
libopensync1exp7-dev - Headers and static libraries for libopensync
```

So it's not in the repository. You need to download the .DEB files and install them (trough software-center or Gdebi).

Hereby the (direct) links:

- multisync-tools

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/multisync/multisync/0.72/libmultisync-plugin-evolution_0.72-1_i386.deb

[ multisync0.90 (0.92.0~svn355-2) unstable; urgency=low ]

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/multisync0.90/multisync-tools_0.92.0~svn355-2_i386.deb

- opensync-plugin-synce

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/synce-sync-engine/opensync-plugin-synce_0.15-2_all.deb

- synce-sync-engine

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/synce-sync-engine/synce-sync-engine_0.15-2_all.deb

Please keep me informed.

Kind regards,

Ilias el Matani

Comment: Hellos,
Thanks for the answer, but when I try to install opensync-plugin-synce it says the dependency opensynce-module-python is not resolved and when I try to install libmultisync-plugin it says that dependency bonobo(>=1.0.22) is not satisfied. 
I think the problem is that the bonobo is now libbonobo2 or something. :?

Comment: actually i stumbled upon this:[link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21948/syncing-wm6-evolution-opensync-module-python-missing) So this is a problem I think

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to sync contacts, calendar and notes from my Windows Mobile 6 HTC Touch Cruise to my Ubuntu 11.10 laptop. I'm following the guide: http://www.tuxradar.com/content/hassle-free-mobile-phone-syncing which says it should be working. Maybe we can work together to get it done!

I managed to install opensync-plugin-synce in the following way, using a terminal window:

```
# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:opensync/opensync-0.22
# sudo apt-get update
# sudo apt-get install opensync-module-python
# sudo apt-get install opensync-plugin-synce
```